# Why inbuilt sort is not able to sort map of vectors?

Tags: c++, sorting, dictionary, vector

**Why STL sort is not applicable on map < int, vector < int > > ?**

*Am i missing something, or do i need to make something like compare function to sort. Can anybody give some ideas.*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
int main(){

    std::map<int,std::vector<int>> map1;

    map1[0].push_back(3);
    map1[0].push_back(2);
    map1[0].push_back(1);

    map1[1].push_back(3);
    map1[1].push_back(2);
    map1[1].push_back(1);

    for(auto i : map1){

       std::cout<< i.first << " --> ";

       for(auto j : i.second){

           std::cout<<j<<" ";
          }
   std::cout<<"\n";
   }

   for(auto i : map1){
      std::sort(i.second.begin(), i.second.end());
   }

   std::cout<<"\n";

   for(auto i : map1){

      std::cout<< i.first << " --> ";

      for(auto j : i.second){

         std::cout<<j<<" ";
      }
   std::cout<<"\n";
   }

 return 0;
 }
```

> Output before and after sorting is same.
>
> 0 --> 3 2 1
>
> 1 --> 3 2 1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When looping over the entries in your `map1`, you *copy* each node. The sorting is hence performed on an independent, newly created instance of `std::vector<int>`, and changes to this variable local to the loop (e.g. sorting it) are already lost on the next iteration.

You need to change the central range based for loop to

```
for(auto& i : map1) {
   //   ^ Loop over references to map nodes, not copies!
   std::sort(i.second.begin(), i.second.end());
}
```

Just as a side note, when you can use C++17, you might want to employ structured bindings to make the loop more expressive by

```
for(auto& [key, vec] : map1) {
   std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
}
```

Comment: Can you explain it in a more detail , how it worked and why?

Comment: Well, the reason should be in the answer already. With `for (auto i : someRange)`, you _copy_ each item in the range. This is different from `for (auto& i : someRange)`, where you loop over a _reference_, not a copy, of each item. References are an alias for an object in memory, whereas copies clone the object and create an identical one.